# ERC1155 - add custom operators to operatorRegistry

Tags: solidity, opensea, erc-1155

I'm developing an ERC1155 upgradeable contract that has to be OpenSea compatible as well.

One of the requests is to have an operator address that's not the owner, and another one is to have a trader contract, a separate contract that handles trading of the NFTs and calls the ERC1155 to execute a tradeFrom.

Since it has to be OpenSea compatible, I need to implement DefaultOperatorFilterer, and add the onlyAllowedOperator clause to the functions.

But I need to be able to call the tradeFrom and mint functions from the operator address and the trader contract and those two addresses are not in the registry.

Is there a way to add those addresses to the OperatorFilterRegistry somehow? or should I just create MyOwnOperatorFilterer and create a separate list of allowed internal addresses?